# Redirect a URL with parameter to another parameter url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

i'm searching for my redirect solution since last night.

I'm using wordpress with the search&filter plugin. But it uses for the results the wrong taxonomy tag. I can't overwrite the taxonomy...
 Here comes my soultion for my problem. I want to redirect the wrong url with parameters to the right one.

My old URL is: /category/familien?ortregion=aichach 
My new URL should be: /category/familien?ort=aichach

This is my .htaccess approach, but my problem is to rewrite the the specific parameter.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ortregion=aichach$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/category/familien?ort=aichach$ %{REQUEST_URI}? [NC,L,R=301]
```

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)(ortregion|ort)=[^&]+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/category/familien/? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Unfortunately happens nothing. But i like the approach. I also tried this: `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)ortregion(.*)$` `RewriteRule /category/familien /category/familien%1ort%2`

Answer (score 0):

I think it may works for you. You don't need to alter .htaccess rule, you need to add a new rewrite rule using WordPress rewrite API.

/* Custom Hook - Taxanomy Rewrite*/

function your_plugin_rewrite_rule() {

```
add_rewrite_rule("^taxonomy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)",'index.php?post_type=$matches[2]&taxonomy=$matches[1]','top');
```

}

add_action('init','your_plugin_rewrite_rule');

**(OR)**

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)ortregion(.*)$

RewriteRule /blog/category/familien /blog/category/familien%1ort%2

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ortregion=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^category/familien$ %{REQUEST_URI}?ort=%1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Mh won't work eighter either... Do i need mod_rewrite?

Comment: It must work! Yes, you need mod_rewrite. I added the activation in the code. Look at your error logs for other issues.